# PHP find character by pattern in string and replace it

Tags: php, string, preg-replace, str-replace

Here is a string:

```
$str = "Discount 5.5@, Update T@";
```

I want to replace symbol '@' to '%' but only if it has numbers (int or dec) before:

```
"Discount 5.5%, Update T@"
```

I use:

```
preg_replace("/[0-9.]*@/", "%", $str);
```

But it just removes any number before % sign, what I do worng?

Comment: The `.` in `[]` means almost any character with some modifiers all. Its not `\.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my comment above. I would suggest a bit different expression:

```
preg_replace("/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\s*)\@/", "$1$2%", $str);
```

This expression will match **5@**, but **5.5@** as well (with or without floating point). However it will not match **5.@**.

`\d` means numbers, equal to `[0-9]`, the `+` (plus) means 1 or more, but not 0 occurrences. The second expression starting with with `?:` (which means not to match as group) means to find . (dot) immediately after the first number sequence and to be followed by numbers - whole zero or one time (not to match **5.15.25@**).

We then check for a spaces (0 or more times), then we turn them back after replacing with `$2`.

Comment: Great! How about if 5.5@ or 5.5 @   space between?

Comment: @KenTang, if you dedicate one week to test and learn regular expressions you will see it is not so hard. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=\d)\@/', '%', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

First check the string if there are numbers in it. Than do a simple str_replace.

```
$str = 'Discount 5.5@, Update T@';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
if(!empty($matches)) { 
   str_replace('@','%', $str);
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking it before with preg_match_all(); and dont use preg_replace right away?

Comment: @Xatenev because of the OP's title

Comment: Well a preg_replace(); would fit. in his answer hes already using peg_replace() too